# Weird link issue in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several `<a>` tags in my codes.

However, after the user click the `<a>` tag, the browser will jump to the top portion of the page.

For example:

```
texts
…..
elements
…...
texts
…..
elements
…...
texts
…..
elements
…...

//the user has to scroll down to here to see the <a> tag.
//once click, the page will jump to the top (scroll to top) for some reason.
<a href = '#' >click here</a>
```

I know I probably not giving enough information but I was wondering if anyone can think of a reason for this weird thing. I didn't create the original codes and there are many codes in the file.. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: It's supposed to be that way. If you don't want it to rise to the top add the [`onclick` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html) to your link, `onclick="return false;"`.

Comment: So why are you using an anchor tag if you don't want default behaviour to happen?

Comment: guys. I am stupid..I totally forget about it. I thought it's something in my codes. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a hastag `#` for the `href` attribute in an anchor `<a>` tag will cause the link to jump to the top.

```
<a href='#'>click here</a>
```

You can specific an ID to jump to by including the ID in the anchor tag, directly after a hashtag.

For example:

By clicking on:

```
<a href='#myElement'>Go to My Element</a>
```

The page will jump to:

```
<div id='myElement"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href^=#]').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a link to behave like a link, use a different element. Use CSS to give it the correct appearance and hover behavior, if that is your reason for using a link.

Answer (score 0):

If an element was given an id then:

```
<a href = '#someid' >click here</a>
```

would jump to that location in the page (putting that element at the top of the page). Without an id being specified, '#' just causes it to jump to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

That's the behavior of an [anchor tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.2).  When a user clicks on an anchor tag (a link) the browser will follow the `href` value of that tag.

The `#` reference is the standard way to reference the top of the current document.  So when a user clicks on `<a href="#">click here</a>` the browser will take the user to the top of the current document.

It's not a weird thing, it's how links work in HTML.